# Allow application to bind to port 80/443 on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, http, ports

I really really need to allow an application to bind on port 80 and 443 on Windows. I understand that this is somehow blocked by `http.sys`. Is it possible to disable http.sys temporarily so this application works?

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:
a) check which process has 80/443 with [TCPView](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) - look for http(s) in the "Local Port" column
b) reconfigure or stop the process you found

Method 2: add another IP address to the system, if your application can bind to a specific IP